# jquery popup box to get value and display in a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you tell me how to create a popup box.

html is

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Involved</strong></td>
    <td><button>Add data<button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="list"  class="ir-shade">
    <td><span class="delete_icon">x</span>Attila Hun</td>            
</tr>
```

In html i had created a table and in one of the  a buttton called `"add data"` is created.While pressing that button a popup box with title and a close button with text area and a `"ok" button` will open.When i click `ok button` the entered data should displayed in a `<td>`,namely `"Attila Hun"` in html.

I gone through jQuery tutorials.I am posting this since i am not able to reproduce this from the jquery forum.Please help me to do this.

**jquery** is

```
jQuery(function($) {  

     $("a.topopup").click(function() {
            loading(); 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                loadPopup();  
            }, 500); 
      return false;
      });

      function loading() {
         $("div").show();  
      }

     var popupStatus = 0; 

     function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { 
            closeloading(); 
            $("#toPopup").show();        
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { 
            $("#toPopup").hide("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").hide("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  
        }
    }     

$("#save").on("click",function(){
    $("a.topopup").after("<b/>" + $("#textval").val());
    $("#toPopup").hide();
});    
});
```

**css**

```
 #backgroundPopup { 

    position: fixed;    
    display:none;    
    height:100%;    
    width:100%;    
}

#toPopup { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;    
    border: 4px solid #ccc;    
    display: none;    
    font-size: 14px;    
    left: 80%;    
    margin-left: -402px;    
    position: fixed;    
    top: 50%;    
    width: 270px;
    height:70px;
}
```

This is the code i tried,i am not getting the expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a popup or td?

Comment: Please post codes that you tried.

Comment: @Basarat Ali - I want a popup box

Comment: you may want to read this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: @Kishor Subedi i updated my code can you please provide me solution

Comment: Hi,can i get some other answer for this

Comment: @user2161650 added solution please check it

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, the following works:

```
$('tbody button.add').click(function (e) {
    // stops any default actions the button might have:
    e.preventDefault();
    // finds the 'Attila the Hun' text
    var newText = $(this)
    // traversing to the nearest 'tr' element
    .closest('tr')
    // moves to the next sibling, finds the 'td', retrieves the contents
    .next().find('td').contents()
    // filters out any child nodes that are not textNodes
    .filter(function () {
        // by returning only those nodes that *are* textNodes
        return this.nodeType == 3;
        // retrieves the text
    }).text();

    // updates the text of the '#output' element (whatever this might be)
    $('#output').text(function (i, t) {
        /* checks the user wants to add that new data/text.
           If so, it returns the old text (t) + newText;
           if not it returns only the old text */
        return confirm('Add new data?') ? (t + ' ' + newText) : t;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw85b/1/).

To explicitly *show* the new data (in the confirm dialogue), simply concatenate the `newText` variable into the string:

```
return confirm('Add new data: "' + newText + '"') ? (t + ' ' + newText) : t;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw85b/2/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a popup I recommend you look at jquery UI Dialog:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/H2rBP/

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Involved</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="but">Add data
            <button>
    </td>
</tr>
<div id="dialog" title="Attila Hun" style="display:none">Your content</div>
```

and

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#but").on("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
```